# Representing $i = \sqrt(-1)$ as a complex exponential

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

We have euler's formula which is $$e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$$

If we just want $i$ then we need to get rid of the cosine,
$$i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}) } = 0 + 1\cdot i = i$$

However, this is has always bothered me. Because $e^{i\theta}$ maps to a circle in the imaginary plane, we have

$$e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}) } = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)}$$ for all integer values of k. But the value of $e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)}$shouldn't be $i$ right? Yet,

$$e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)} = e^{i \frac{pi}{2} } \cdot e^{i (2\pi k)}$$ for $k = 1,2,3,4,5,....$ $e^{i (2\pi k)} = 1$ so, $$e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)} = i \cdot 1 = 1$$

Can someone please explain why this is? I'm changing the value of the exponent, yet my total value is still the same...

Comment: The complex exponential can take the same value for two different exponents. We say that the complex exponential is not *injective*. So, indeed, you have $e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi*k)} = i$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: We have indeed $$e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k\right)} = i \cdot 1 = i$$

Comment: MathJax hint:  for multicharacter arguments of square roots, enclose them in braces and the upper bar extends over them, so \sqrt{(-1)} gives $\sqrt{(-1)}$.  It works with superscripts and subscripts, too.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be i?

Comment: @user But does that mean $i^i$ is not unique? 

$$i^i = e^{{(i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k))}^i} = e^{(-1 (\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k))}$$ which takes on different, real values based upon the value of k. However $i^i$ should be a constant, right?

Comment: @BigBear What does $i^i$ mean ?

Comment: $i ^ i = \sqrt{-1}^{\sqrt{-1}}$

Comment: @BigBear $i^i$ is not always a constant. What you have proved is that there is different values of $i^i$.

Comment: @personcallednothing Why is that the case? If I'm raising a constant number to a constant number, shouldn't a get another constant number?

Comment: It is the same reason as saying that $\sqrt{-1}$ can be $i$ or $-i$. In general, you should not use the symbol $\sqrt{}$ with negative real numbers. If you don't give a precise definition, then this is not well defined. This is the same, even worth, with powers : in the context of real numbers, $a^b$ means $e^{b \ln(a)}$ and is defined only if $a > 0$ : you can extend powers to complex numbers, but then it inlvolves complex $\ln$, which (if you don't take care), is not well-defined.

Comment: @BigBear You said that $e^{i\theta}$ is a circle, so if you rotate by $2\pi+\theta, 4\pi+\theta$ and so on, the powers are different but the values are same, so there's no guarantee that they're a constant

Comment: This is no different from the number $1$ (or any other complex number $z$ as $|z|e^{i\text{Arg}(z)+i2k\pi}$) as represented by $e^{i\pi 0 +i 2k\pi}$.  Why do you view $i$ as a special case.